# Discover linux interface name based on IP address

Tags: linux, ansible

I have code which search specified IP in linux system:

```
- name: find IP
  set_fact:
    ip: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses}}"
  when: "item.startswith('10.')"
```

And works ok, but I can't find out how to discover interface name based on IP from fact "ip".
Does anybody could give some advice or maybe have some example how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible provides a list of interfaces in the `ansible_interfaces` fact. You can use this to iterate over available interfaces, checking each one for a given ip address.

That ends up being trickier than it sounds because you'll need to construct fact names, which means rather than something simple like:

```
ansible_eth0
```

You instead need:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_%s" % item]
```

An additional complication is that Ansible divides ip addresses into "primary" (which is `ansible_eth0.ipv4.address`) and "secondaries" (`ansible_eth0.ipv4_secondaries`), where the latter is a list of dictionaries with `address` keys.  Assuming that we are iterating with `item` set to an interface name, we can get the primary address like this:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_%s" % item].ipv4.address
```

But! That will fail for interfaces that don't have an ipv4 address assigned, or that don't have a corresponding `ansible_<interface>` fact for some reason.  So we need to deal gracefully with that situation:

```
(hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_%s" % item]|default({}).get('ipv4', {}).get('address')
```

This uses the `default` filter to ensure that we start with a dictionary, and then we use a few levels of Python's `.get(key, default)` method.

Checking against the secondary addresses is similar but requires that we use the `map` filter because `ipv4_secondaries` gives us a list of dictionaries and what we really want is a list of addresses (so that we can check if our target address is `in` that list):

```
((hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item]|default({}))
.get('ipv4_secondaries'))|map(attribute='address')|list
```

Putting it all together:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    target_address: 192.168.122.1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        target_interface: "{{ item }}"
      when: >
        (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item]|default({}))
        .get('ipv4', {}).get('address') == target_address
        or
        target_address in ((hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_%s' % item]|default({}))
        .get('ipv4_secondaries'))|map(attribute='address')|list
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"

    - debug:
        msg: >-
          found interface {{ target_interface }}
          with address {{ target_address }}
```

If I run this on my system, the playbook run concludes with:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "found interface virbr0 with address 192.168.24.1"
}
```

If I run:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e target_address=192.168.1.75
```

I get:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "found interface eth0 with address 192.168.1.75"
}
```

As you can see from the above, this isn't exactly the sort of task that Ansible is meant for.  You would probably be better off stuffing all this logic into an Ansible module so that you could use Python (or some other language) to perform the lookup in a more graceful fashion.

**Update**

[Here](https://github.com/larsks/stackoverflow-example-45659201) is a module-based solution to the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's what I'm looking for.